# iphone texts don't send or receive with some contacts. Words with family members in same Verizon account

Tags: iphone, sms

Texts send and receive with my wife and others on our family account.
nobody outside my account.

When I send I get "Message Send Failures".
And I dont receive for same contacts.

Cellular provider:  Verizon

Device: iPhone 13 max with latest IOS.

Comment: If they are SMS (text messages), then this is an issue for Verizon.  If they are iMessages, then we have more to work with.  What color are the "bubbles"?